# CSS divide child tr elements into groups based on td content

Tags: html, css

Not sure of the proper title for this. I have a table where I can not edit the HTML.

I want to select the tr element that contains td `colspan="7"` and all of its siblings until the next tr element that contains td `colspan+"7"` so that I can add a color gradient border that begins and ends at the next tr element that contains td `colspan="7"`. This is a responsive table.

I was able to select the first tr (which I envision as a header) using the following syntax but can't figure out how to select that and its `tr` siblings without the entire table being selected. This data changes so there are more or less tr elements below each "header". I think that rules out nth-child selectors.

I thought turning the first tr it into a header using the display property would get me on the right track but can't figure the rest out.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/john1968/8qw1ndar/)

```
tr td[colspan="7"] {
display: table-header-group;
}
```

To test I tried to change the background of the first child but had no luck using:

```
tr td[colspan="7"] > td:nth-child(1) {
background: blue;
}
```

CURRENT HTML STRUCTURE

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle" colspan="7"><b>Swimmer, 1</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle" colspan="7"><b>Swimmer, 2</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: tr td[colspan="7"] does not select the tr, it selects any td with that colspan attribute within a tr. You can't select a parent div  using its children. That is you can't go 'back' in CSS.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you. Is there no other way? Can we use calc to get the total rows between every iteration of tr td[colspan="7"]

Comment: Hi, I was just putting up an answer to at least get some division when your comment came in. I can't see a way of using calc to get the number of rows - CSS isn't very good (well, doesn't at all really does it) at knowing anything about content. It would be interesting if someone could correct me on that.

Answer (score 1):

If we give the colspan td a background image (or possibly a top border, I haven't tried that) and the table a set of background images at the two sides and bottom (or ditto on border) then we get at least some division of the sections although the treatment of the linear gradient wont be exactly as you wanted it as there is a variable number of tds in each.

Here's what we get using the HTML given in the question:

[image]

```css
table {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue), linear-gradient(to right, blue, red), linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, red);
  background-size: 2px calc(100% - 4px), calc(100% - 2px) 2px, 2px calc(100% - 4px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 2px, 0 calc(100% - 2px), calc(100% - 2px) 2px;
}

tr td[colspan="7"] {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  background-size: calc(100% - 2px) 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle" colspan="7"><b>Swimmer, 1</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle" colspan="7"><b>Swimmer, 2</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Event</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Best Time</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Standard</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>P/F/T</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Swim Date</b></td>
      <td class="topTdStyle"><b>Meet Name</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```